# Generic Repository apply filter based on entity type

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I have a generic repository:

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
 {
    public List<T> GetAllList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return GetQueryable().Where(filter).ToList();
    }

    private IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
        query = ApplyTagFilter(query)
        return query;
    }

    private IQueryable<T> ApplyTagFilter(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
       //if T is ITagableEntity filter by token somehow
       if(typeof(ITagableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
       {
          //does not work and looks ugly :(
          return (query as IQueryable<ITagableEntity>)
             .Where(q => q.tagtoken > 10) as IQueryable<T>;
       }
       else
       {
           return query;
       }
    }
 }
```

Some of my entities are tagable, ie implement ITagableEntity interface:

```
public interface ITagableEntity : IEntity
{
    int tagtoken { get; set; }
}
```

How can I implement if condition in `ApplyTagFilter` method ? What is the best way to approach it ? The way I tried does not work and looks ugly. Generic parameter T is of type IEntity, but ITagableEntities inherits from IEntity, thus I have to cast back and forth in order to apply the filter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about more specific repository: `public class TagableEntityRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : ITagableEntity`. The more entity specific methods you have the more repositories you have, but they all derive from the main one.

Comment: @FCin not all of my entities are ITagableEntity. Only some of them.

Comment: Yes, that's why you would use this repository only for `ITagableEntity`'s. For `Entity`'s you would use the `Repository<T>`. You would have two repositories.

Comment: @FCin, thank you for the idea. I will try.

Comment: In the future you might want to handle for example `IClonableEntity` or `ISaveableEntity` and it would make your `Repository<T>` huge, so dividing it into many specific repositories might help. Btw. if you are using `entity framework` you might want to dump repositories and switch to writing services.

Comment: what is the purpose to have repository and expose IQueryable? with EF repositories are just redundant layer of abstraction, use DbContent and DbSet directly from you BL or something

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov, the repository in the example does not expose IQueryable. The only public method which it exposes returns List<T>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by implementing an idea proposed by **FCin** and **VorobeY1326**. I marked `GetQueryable()` as `protected virtual` and overrode it in `TagableRepository` class.

```
public class TagableRepository<T> : Repository<T> where T : class, ITagableEntity
{
    protected override IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
    {
        return base.GetQueryable().Where(q => q.tagtoken > 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you really consider creating some specific repository for taggable entities.

But if you want to make this code work — you can use cast.

```
return query.Cast<ITagableEntity>()
                .Where(q => q.tagtoken > 10)
                .Cast<T>();
```